# Creating Portfolio in Python using pyrtfolio

Tags: python, dataframe, portfolio

I wanted to create a portfolio of few Indian stocks using the python package pyrtfolio. On running the code, I am getting the error as follows :-
No results were found for the introduced stock_symbol in the specified stock_country

The code is given below:-

```
import pandas as pd
import pyrtfolio as pf
from pyrtfolio.StockPortfolio import StockPortfolio
import investpy 

portfolio = StockPortfolio()
data1 = pd.read_csv("C:\FORTIS.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = pd.read_csv("C:\IDFC.csv")
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = pd.read_csv("C:\M&M.csv")
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

portfolio.add_stock(stock_symbol="FORTIS",stock_country = "india",purchase_date='15/5/2017',num_of_shares=271,cost_per_share=205.76)
portfolio.add_stock(stock_symbol="IDFCFIRSTB",stock_country = "India",purchase_date='08/6/2017',num_of_shares=950,cost_per_share=58.7)
portfolio.add_stock(stock_symbol="M&M",stock_country = "india",purchase_date='22/2/2018',num_of_shares=78,cost_per_share=714.9)

print(portfolio.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Problem

`read_csv` returns a `DataFrame`.

## Solution

Replace this:

```py
data1 = pd.read_csv("C:\FORTIS.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

with this:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\FORTIS.csv")
```